# Retrieving Superfeedr aggregated feeds to the node library

Tags: node.js, xmpp, websub, superfeedr

I’ve successfully created aggregated feeds using the hub.callback mechanism as described in your blog (https://blog.superfeedr.com/combining-feeds/).

However, your [NodeJS library](https://github.com/superfeedr/superfeedr-node) doesn’t describe how to pull aggregated feeds… I was able to pull single feeds (hub.topic), but can’t seem to get it to work with aggregated feeds… How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The Superfeedr NodeJS API only implements the Superfeedr XMPP API, not the "normal" one. The XMPP API does not support fetching combined feeds.

Comment: Does that imply there is no way to retrieve Aggregated feeds to NodeJS?